# Price Sets - Won't let me use recurring contributions

Tags: civimember, contributions, price-sets, recurring-contributions

I'm running civicrm 4.6.10, drupal 7.41, and I'm trying to add a field to a price set that would let users select from a couple of different price levels for membership.

- Maximum Dues $33
- Regular Dues $22
- Minimum Dues $11
- Sub-Minimum Dues $6

They are each attached to a membership type that has recurring payments listed as an option.

However, I keep getting this error.

"You can include auto-renew membership choices for only one price field in a price set. Another field in this set already contains one or more auto-renew membership options."

I get this error even when there are not other fields in the set, or when I only make one option is the field for the memberships (like just listing maximum)

Any ideas?  Is this something I'm doing wrong or possibly a bug?

Comment: I found this link to a bug in a newer version- civicrm 4.7.2 : https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18050

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a bug that I was able to fix by updating to the latest version of civicrm 4.7.4